# i need to resolve error highlighted in my question

Tags: python

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\HTCOMP~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_6676/988855770.py in <module>
----> 1 sns.distplot(data_no_mv['body'])
NameError: name 'sns' is not defined
```

Comment: I would need some code to be sure but have you imported `sns` ?

Comment: `import seaborn as sns`

Comment: Please, check [ask]. Always provide [mre]

Answer (score 0):

`sns` usually represents the seaborn library, so you might need to add `import seaborn as sns` to the beginning of your code. You might already have done this and something else might be wrong, but it is hard to tell without the code.